# Collecting values across multiple fields for a given key - Apache Spark (Scala)

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I have a Scala Data frame in the below format:

[image]

I need an o/p in the below format :
[image]

The o/p needs to be written to a json file .

Comment: Please don't put code and output images if some one wants to use it for answer they cant. and also put inline images of you want to  use images rather than links. you have to present your code snippet of what you have tried and what is the error. it will reveal your effort and where you are wrong. see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking question. add relevant tags apache is not definitely relevant tag.. corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is. Change the formatting according to your need.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("arr", format_string("{%d,%d,%d}", $"pd_id", $"score",$"rank"))
.groupBy("event_tra", "customer", "itemId", "ckey").agg(collect_list("arr").as("collection"))
.select(format_string("{%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s}", $"event_tra", $"customer", $"itemId", $"ckey", col("collection").toString).as("data"))
```